# Selecting two column values from Datagridview and displaying it in Message Box

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview which populates caller number and called number, upon selecting the two column values, and click a button a message box should display the selected column values. How this can be achieved. Any sample code would be of great help.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code, or a better description of what you have? It isn't clear what you mean by "selecting the two column value". To grab the value from a datagridviewcell is very simple - all cells have a value property and cells can be referenced by their row and column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at DataGridView's [SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) property. Your button click method can do something along those lines then:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in this.dataGridView.SelectedCells)
    {
        message.AppendLine("Value = " + cell.Value);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
}
```

This will display all values of selected **cells** in message box.

Comment: Will the **SelectedCells** have the cells from the two columns the user so called selected ?

Comment: `SelectedCells` will contain **all** selected cells combination. You can access rows/columns with appropriate properties (namely, through `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex`). Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: What i meant is this is dependent on the **SelectionMode** of the DataGridView and if its cell select it will always have one cell. Hope you got my point